# Choosing entries that are approximately x-apart

Tags: r

I have a vector whose entries represent locations on a sequence. The distance between the entries on the sequence is in the range 1 to 10^7. For a given x I need to find a pair of entries in a distance approximately x.

Example:

v = [1 2 3 1000 1002 2000]

Then for x=1 we can get entries [1,2],[1,3],[2,3],[1000,1002]
and for x=1000 we can get [1,1000],[2,1000],[1002,2000] etc.

Any ideas of how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a function like this would work:

```
dist = function(vec, margin) {
    d = expand.grid(vec, vec[2:length(vec)])
    d$diff = abs(abs(d$Var1 - d$Var2) - margin)
    d[order(d$diff),] 
}
```

So running:

```
v = c(1, 2, 3, 1000, 1002, 2000)
dist(v, 1000)
```

would output:

```
   Var1 Var2 diff
5  1002    2    0
18 2000 1000    0
20    2 1002    0
28 1000 2000    0
11 1002    3    1
...
```

A data frame with all pairs sorted in order of difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all pairwise distances by:

```
dist(v, method="manhattan")
```

So `abs(dist(v, method="manhattan")-x)` will give the lowest values for the nearest distance to x.  You can get the `order` of this to sort entries, find where it is zero, ...

Comment: Thanks. I thought about something similar but I wanted to randomize it more.